# Save multiple url to pdf

Tags: pdf, chrome, pdf-generation, url

I have multiple(50-60) blog URL from a website that I want to save as single or multiple PDFs. How can I do that

Comment: You want to save the web page contents and concatenate all of it into a PDF? Split those tasks into a web page downloader, a script which invokes it, and a PDF joiner or combiner.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with wkhtmltopdf command line binary.

https://wkhtmltopdf.org/

something like

```
wkhtmltopdf url1 url2 url3 output.pdf
```

will result in a single PDF containing all the content from the URL's you pass in.

Comment: I've downloaded the zip file of set-up from the website but unable to move forward. Can you explain how to execute? Where to run this code you provided

Comment: I assume you are on Linux? Either way there should be a binary called wkhtmltopdf, that you just call the above command from the command line of your terminal. no code, just command line. If that doesn't help post more info on what the error is (screen shots help a lot)